# Authenticating users and uploading content with Services module

Tags: files, services

I am trying to learn how to set up a service that will accept http-posts including user login and password, authenticate the user, then allow the user to upload a file that will be used to create a new piece of content.  I could not find any good resources explaining how to handle user authentication with the services module nor did I find any good resources about how an upload or content creating could be accomplished.  Does anyone know of any such resources I may have missed?

Comment: What language are you using to consume the service? Is it PHP?

Comment: The client is actually a common lisp based application that will be uploading the file.  But should this really matter as long as it can send a properly formatted http-post?

Comment: Not really no, it's just there are lots of code tutorials out there using PHP, C#, Java etc. The link in Kyle Browning's answer should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/736522 should help you.

Comment: Normally, just posting a URL isn't an answer.  A little context about why the link is useful or a short summary of the link is appreciated.